# placa veículos padrão Mercosul?

Tags: java, regex

Estou trabalhando em um projeto e não sei como fazer. Como no enunciado, preciso validar as placas com o padrão do Mercosul, eu tenho um método para validar as placas antigas dos veículos.

```
public boolean validaPlaca(String placa) {
    boolean result = false;

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{3}-\\d{4}");
    Matcher mat = pattern.matcher(placa);
    if (!mat.matches()) {
        result = false;
    } else {
        result = true;

    }
    return result;

}
```

Agora para validar a placa padrão Mercosul não sei como fazer. Já fiz:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{3}\d{1}[A-Z]{3}\d{2}");
```

E também:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{3}[0-9][A-Z][0-9]{2}");
```

Nenhuma funcionou, lembrando que o padrão Mercosul é *AAA3B11*. Os 3 primeiros dígitos são letras, o quarto é um numero, o quinto uma letra e o sexto e sétimo um numero.

Comment: O que é "não funcionou"? Deu um erro? Quais formatos passaram na validação e não deveriam ter passado?

Comment: Utilize `^[A-Z]{3}\\d[A-Z]\\d{2}$`. Exemplo: https://ideone.com/Vq8yi8

Comment: Opa blz meu amigo, na verdade ele nao verifica, passa direto.....ou seja aceita qualquer coisa

Comment: Tem certeza que o problema não é em outro ponto do código? Porque a regex está certa: https://ideone.com/e97vyf - Talvez a melhoria sugerida pelo Valdeir ajude, pois aí garante que string só tem a placa e nada mais. E também dá pra simplificar bastante seu método `validaPlaca`, veja: https://ideone.com/WMwsKW

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observe que o seu método é *validaPlaca*, portanto deve validar as placas antigas (que ainda vão ficar em circulação) e também as placas novas no modelo Mercosul.

Então a sua *regex* deve validar os dois formatos. Uma expressão para validar os dois formatos ao mesmo tempo seria este: `[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{2}|[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}`

Mas ainda há considerações a fazer, por exemplo, a placa é do padrão Mercosul mas cada país [tem uma combinação de letras e números diferentes](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placas_de_identifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_ve%C3%ADculos_no_Mercosul).

Por exemplo:

- Argentina: AB123CD
- Brasil: ABC1D23
- Uruguai: ABC1234
- Paraguai: 123ABCD

Em resumo, adotaria a mesma expressão regular que a Receita Federal faz na emissão dos Documentos Fiscais Eletrônicos (NF-e, CT-e e MDF-e) que é esse: `[A-Z]{2,3}[0-9]{4}|[A-Z]{3,4}[0-9]{3}|[A-Z0-9]{7}`, desta forma não ficaria restrito a validação das placas do Brasil.

Comment: Obg LGregianin, funcionou perfeito vlw

Comment: @WesleySouza, marca a resposta como solução da pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, pelo que pude observar a segunda regex que você exemplificou está correta `"[A-Z]{3}[0-9][A-Z][0-9]{2}"`.

Creio então que o erro esteja na função que valida a placa e utiliza essa regex.

Tente utiliza a função abaixo para ver se funciona, pelo que testei aqui ta funcionando certinho.

```
public boolean validarPlaca(String placa) {
    boolean placaValida = true;

    if (placa.length() > 0) {
        if (placa.length() < 7) {
            placaValida = false;
        } else {
            if (!placa.matches("[A-Z]{3}[0-9][A-Z][0-9]{2}")) {
                placaValida = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return placaValida;
}
```

Dica: Utilize o site [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) para verificar se suas regex estão ou não certas.

*Fonte:* [Placa Mercosul - Alberto Marianno](https://medium.com/@albertomarianno/placa-mercosul-67151bebc00c)

Answer (score 0):

Segue minha função de verificação:

```
if (txtPlaca.getText().isEmpty()) {
    ValidationFields.checkEmptyFields(txtPlaca);
    Alert dlg = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
    dlg.setContentText("Preencha o campo PLACA!!!");
    dlg.showAndWait();
    txtPlaca.requestFocus();
    return;
} else {
    boolean valida = true;
    String validar = txtPlaca.getText();
    System.out.println("validar placa : " + validar);

    if (validaPlaca(validar) == valida || validaPlacaMercosul(validar) == valida) {

    } else {

        Alert dlg = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
        dlg.setContentText("Placa digitada não e válida!!!");
        dlg.showAndWait();
        txtPlaca.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    placa = txtPlaca.getText();

}
```

Comment: Isso é uma solucao pra sua pergunta? Se nao for, nao é o local certo de postar. Voce deve adicionar codigos complementares na propria pergunta, clicando em EDITAR/

Comment: Valores *booleanos* não precisam ser comparados com `==`, basta fazer `if (validaPlaca(validar) || validaPlacaMercosul(validar))`